# How to display UTF-8 correctly with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, utf-8

This is error:
[image]

my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thịnh Vượng</title>
    <meta content-type="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Thịnh Vượng</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Trang chủ</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Trang chủ<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Thiết kế</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thi công</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sửa chữa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Điện nước - Điều hòa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tư vấn phong thủy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tin tức</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Liên hệ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>
        <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure how you're getting that output. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd81p1tr/)

Comment: Thank Tim for your testing. I try copying content, then create new file, then paste clipboard into, then UTF-8 font work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the HTML5 approach

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Also, make sure that the text editor you're working in **saves the file in UTF-8** format.

Comment: I use phpStorm 8, set charset in document and IDE is `UTF-8`, but not work.