# Bootstrap Table - Json problems with accents

Tags: json, bootstrap-table

I am loading a table, with the plugin Table Bootstrap, using json, in json file, i have literals with accents.

But, in the web, the accents not are shown correctly.

I am using, this meta in tag head:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Which is the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the font you are using supports accents?

Answer (score 0):

try escaping your literals with accents like this \à

Answer (score 0):

Answered at [How to display UTF-8 correctly with Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021399/how-to-display-utf-8-correctly-with-bootstrap)

**Important**: You must save the file using UTF-8 encoding.